# WPF Datagrid Popup Placement

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am showing a Popup when users double click a DataGrid row, is there a way to show this popup at the right of the SelectedItem?

Here is my current code:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=dgWarnings}" Placement="Right" Name="InfoPopup" PopupAnimation="Slide" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding ShowInfo}">
```

I obviously cannot bind to the selected item property as this is not a UI item.

As I mentioned I would like to display it on the right hand side of the currently selected item in the datagrid.

Any suggestions?